Left Adjoint From the Category of Topological Groups to the Category of Condensed Groups
In Scholze's Lecture Notes on Condensed Sets, the author states that (Remark 1.8) the functor that takes a topological group $G$ to its condensation $\underline{G}$ has a left-adjoint, but we do not know how to describe it.
In
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/condensed+set
the article states that there is a left-adjoint such that for a condensed group $\underline{G}$, the underlying set is not $\underline{G}(\{*\})$.
It seems to me that the authors of the ncatlab article have some construction in mind, but it's not clear what it should be. Is there a reference for where this adjoint is constructed, or for condensed groups (not necessarily abelian) in general?
